# Get distinct names order by last name

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have below 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE owner (
 id INT NOT NULL,
 first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  owner_id INT NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to the owner table
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am trying to write a query to find all the owners first and last names who has a vehicle of black and sort the owners by last name, and display the names only once if the same owner have the color vehicle multiple times.

```
select first_name, last_name, count(v.id) 
  from owner o join vehicle v on o.id = v.owner_id
  where color = 'black' 
  group by first_name, last_name
  order by last_name;
```

Here how can I avoid the count of vehicles and then later get unique names (first_name, last_name) with results sorted by last_name.

Comment: Just remove count from your query.

Answer (score 5):

An arguably more elegant solution would be to use an `exists` operator instead of joining:

```
SELECT   first_name, last_name
FROM     owner o
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   vehicle v
                 WHERE  v.color = 'black' AND o.id = v.owner_id)
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

Comment: Use `SELECT '8'` or some other simple character instead of `SELECT *` to improve performance.

Comment: @Edward . . . That has no impact on performance.  The `SELECT` expressions in the subquery are ignored.

Comment: This isn't "arguably more elegant".  It is simply better than `select distinct` with a `join`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, the more you know. Is that for the `EXISTS()` function in particular?

Comment: @Edward . . . Yes, specifically for `EXISTS` because it is checking for the existence of rows, not columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm trying to use language that isn't as decisive since I've actually seen people prefer joins in such situations (although I've yet to hear a good reason for this, other than "personal preference")

Comment: @Mureinik . . . The issue isn't the `JOIN`.  The issue is the `SELECT DISTINCT`.  That always incurs overhead for removing duplicates (although in some databases with the appropriate indexing, the overhead might be minimal).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `DISTINCT` operator:

```
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name
  from owner o join vehicle v
    on o.id = v.owner_id
  where LOWER(color) = 'black' 
  order by last_name;
```

I also changed it to look for `'black'` no matter if it's in upper, lower, or mixed case.

Best of luck.

Comment: Wouldn't LOWER affect possible index on the COLOR column?

Comment: Create a function-based index on LOWER(COLOR), e.g. `CREATE INDEX LOWER_COLOR ON VEHICLE  (LOWER(COLOR))`.